# Using drag and drop files or file picker with CustomTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop, customtkinter

I have recently decided to start learning Python and while doing several small projects as a hands-on approach, i discovered the `customtkinter` library (https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) for more modern looking GUI development with Python.

I wanted to do something which either requires a drag-and-drop component for files or a file picker dialogue, which is seemingly *somewhat* present for the original `tkinter` library with the `tkinterdnd2` module, but it doesn't seem to be directly mentioned in the documentation for the `customtkinter` library wrapper.

**Does anyone know how to use drag-and-drop for files with `customtkinter` specifically?**

If there is no direct wrapper with `customtkinter`, is there a way to apply the styles of `customtkinter` to the `tkinderdnd2` module? When using it like this, obviously it just uses the default `tkinter` style:

```
from tkinter import TOP, Entry, Label, StringVar
from tkinterdnd2 import *

def get_path(event):
    pathLabel.configure(text = event.data)

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.geometry("350x100")
root.title("Get file path")

nameVar = StringVar()

entryWidget = Entry(root)
entryWidget.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

pathLabel = Label(root, text="Drag and drop file in the entry box")
pathLabel.pack(side=TOP)

entryWidget.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
entryWidget.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", get_path)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into the source code of `TkinterDnD`:

```py
class Tk(tkinter.Tk, DnDWrapper):
    '''Creates a new instance of a tkinter.Tk() window; all methods of the
    DnDWrapper class apply to this window and all its descendants.'''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.TkdndVersion = _require(self)
```

You can create another custom class using `customtkinter.CTk` instead of `tkinter.Tk`:

```py
from tkinter import StringVar, TOP
from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_ALL
import customtkinter as ctk

class Tk(ctk.CTk, TkinterDnD.DnDWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.TkdndVersion = TkinterDnD._require(self)

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
#ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

def get_path(event):
    pathLabel.configure(text = event.data)

#root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x100")
root.title("Get file path")

nameVar = StringVar()

entryWidget = ctk.CTkEntry(root)
entryWidget.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=5)

pathLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Drag and drop file in the entry box")
pathLabel.pack(side=TOP)

entryWidget.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
entryWidget.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", get_path)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I was considering to dive into the code or even attempt a PR on Github for an added wrapper, but im new to Python as i said so wanted to ensure im not missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: I get "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name" for this example.

Comment: @JasonIvey I don't have such error.  Note that you need to use my custom `Tk` class, not `customtkinter.CTk`.

Answer (score 1):

**FIrst install tkinterdnd2:**

```
pip install tkinterdnd2
```

Now copy the customtkinter folder in the directory where your program is present, browse to this file: `customtkinter>windows>ctk_tk.py`

Then do these changes in the [ctk_tk.py](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/ctk_tk.py) file of customtkinter library.

1. Add this new import: `from tkinterdnd2 import *`
2. Replace (Ctrl+H) this term: `tkinter.Tk` with `TkinterDnD.Tk`.
3. Save the file.

Done!

**Now you can implement this drag and drop feature in your application.**
Example:

```py
import customtkinter
from tkinterdnd2 import DND_FILES

def drop(event):
    # do operations with event.data file
    label.configure(text=event.data)
                    
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("500x200")

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="➕ \nDrag & Drop Here", corner_radius=10, fg_color="blue", wraplength=300)
label.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=40, pady=40)

# Add this 2 lines to make it a dnd widget
label.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
label.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', drop)

root.mainloop()
```